# How to stop execution of a method from within a delegate passed to it and executed by it

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write a method which receives a delegate, and executes that delegate in a loop.
That's not very hard, for example:

```
public static void RunInLoop<T>(IEnumerable<T> someCollection, 
                                 Action<T> action)
{           
        foreach (var item in someCollection)
        {
                action(item);
        }
}
```

However, let's say I would like to give the user of `RunInLoop` means of doing something like `break`, that is - stop the execution of the loop (or just simply return from `RunInLoop`).

What I thought about:

1. Writing a method called `Break()` - which throws a (private) exception, and then surround `action(item)` with try catch, and if I catch my (private) exception- just return. This is not so good if the delegate passed catches `Exception`.
2. Run the `foreach` in a new thread, and implement `Break()` by killing the current thread. Among other reasons, this is not good when using my method in a UI based application (like Silverlight), where sometimes execution must occur in the UI thread.
3. Another suggestion I got was to receive an extra delegate, with a condition that I will check at the end of each execution. I don't like that either because it is not intuitive for the user, and limits the `break` to the end of the iteration. This is my last resort for now though.

So no good solution I could find yet. 
Any suggestions/directions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void RunInLoop<T>(IEnumerable<T> someCollection, 
                                 Func<T, bool> action)
{           
        foreach (var item in someCollection)
        {
                if(action(item))
                     break;
        }
}
```

Have the "action" (should rename it to func if you make this change) return a boolean value indicating whether or not you should continue.

It's also worth mentioning that your origional method is just a `ForEach` extension method.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) is a blog post by Eric Lippert which states why it was intentionally omitted from the framework and why it's really not a good practice (granted a lot of people use it anyway).

Comment: This is actually quite a good idea, although I am still dreaming of an implementation of Break(). I have read Eric Lippert's blog before I started working on this- but my goal is not to implement foreach. I am using it in a class where I do completely different things. This method will eventually be private (but the question still holds). **Thanks alot!**

Comment: well, as for not implementing a foreach, the only difference is the name of the method between your code and his, so you are implementing a foreach. You may be using it locally, not globally, but that doesn't change what it is.  ---  Your comment implies that this doesn't solve your problem; I fail to see what you want to accomplish that this doesn't.  Could you please clarify what you would like to do that this currently does not do?  Maybe post some code of how you would like to use a method that doesn't exist yet so we can see your desired outcome.

Comment: Let's put it this way - your solution solves the problem. It took me some time to understand that it does not fall from my original idea of implementing a Break() method. Even if I don't use this method, my original question still stands, since I will need to run `action` in a loop in a different method, and would still like to allow `break`. Case closed as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use a static/member variable that is a bool.

```
Action
{
    ...
    foreach
        if (!s_KeepGoing)
            break
    ...
}
```

Or if you want flexibility to specify the bool then let the Action take a ref to a bool as a second parameter of a delegate, and check the bool as above.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate<in T>(T type, ref bool keepGoing);

public static void RunInLoop<T>(IEnumerable<T> someCollection, 
                                 MyDelegate<T> action)
{           
        foreach (var item in someCollection)
        {
                action(item, ref s_AnotherKeepGoing);
        }
}
```